# How can I restrict the mouse to just one of my dual monitors during a game?

Tags: mouse, multiple-monitors

I used to use a program called MouseClip, but I cannot find it anymore through Google or Bing.

Are there any alternatives so that my mouse will stay on one monitor? This is really important when playing a game.

Answer (score 1):

MouseClip v1.10 here

http://www.brothersoft.com/d.php?soft_id=199247&url=http%3A%2F%2Fusfiles.brothersoft.com%2Futilities%2Fsystem_utilities%2Fmclip110.zip

Home page for the author of mouseclip
http://adoxa.110mb.com/

I googled "MouseClip software"

Cheers!

May not be the same software you are talking about, another thing you can check is to set your dual monitors (graphics properties) to extend the desktop instead of duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an old zip version of MouseClip on an external hard drive. I installed the program and noticed that it is produced by GetHyper. After Googling for *that* I finally found: http://mc.gethyper.co.uk/

This product seems like it suffers from the ultimate anti-search engine protection.

Comment: Actually, I found MouseClip in about 3 tries on Google.

Comment: Well I respect your GoogleFu then

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for Mac OS X (Full Disclosure: I'm the developer!)

[EdgeCase [Mac App Store]](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/edgecase/id513826860?mt=12)

[image]

Crossing Options (Toggle independently according to taste):

- Bounce on screen edge
- Wait 1/2 second
- Hold [ctrl] or [⌘]
- Cross when dragging

Advanced Options:

- Inverse Hotkey: Bounding edges are only active when you hold the hotkey.
- Main Screen Only: Cursor is only bounded when you're on the main screen with the menu bar.

[EdgeCase [Mac App Store]](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/edgecase/id513826860?mt=12)